# $x^m \equiv 1$ (mod p) has $(m,p-1)$ roots

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Why is the following true?

"$x^m \equiv 1$ (mod p) has $(m,p-1)$ roots."

I know these things which could be relevant:

-$x^{p-1} \equiv 1$ (mod p) for any $(x,p)=1$ by Fermat's Little Theorem

-for any root, the order of the root must divide $m$ by Lagrange's Theorem

-$(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*} $ is cyclic

But still can't put the pieces together.

Comment: It must divide $m$ but also $p-1$, because of Fermat's Little theorem. So it must divide...

Comment: Yes, but why could it not be a divisor of $(m,p-1)$?

Comment: It is a divisor of $gcd(m, p-1)$. Now in a cyclic group of order $n$, and if $d|n$, how many elements of the group have an order that divide $d$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All equalities I write will be mod $p$ when it's clear that they are.

Assume $x^m = 1$. Then the order of $x$ divides $m$, but also $p-1$ by Fermat's Little theorem, so it divides $gcd(m,p-1)$.

Conversely, if the order of $x$ divides $gcd(m,p-1)$, then $x^m = 1$.

Therefore we're just looking for $x$'s whose order divides $gcd(m,p-1)$.

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ and let $d|n$. Then the set $H=\{x\in G\mid $ the order of $x$ divides $d\}$ is obviously a subgroup of $G$ (note that $G$ is abelian), so it is a cyclic subgroup. Its exponent is $d$, since its exponent divides $d$, and $G$ being cyclic, there exists $x\in G$ of order precisely $d$. 
In cyclic subgroups, exponent and order coincide, thus $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $d$ : it has $d$ elements.

Do you see how this solves the question ?

Comment: Yes, we just set $H=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*} $ and $d=gcd(m,p-1)$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

In a cyclic group of order $n$, generated by $\zeta$, the order of the element $\zeta^k$ is equal to $\;\dfrac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [discrete logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) wrt a primitive root $g$ on $$x^m\equiv1\pmod{p^n}$$ for any positive integer $n$

$m$ind$_gx\equiv0\pmod{\phi(p^n)}$

Now use [Linear Congruence Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence) .